# Typos in the blog links prevent some from working

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, blog

The [most recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/19/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/) showcases some of the best questions from the sites that have recently turned 10. Unfortunately, some of the links have typos/formatting errors that break them. Digging into the HTML, the offenders are:

- Graphic Design: `<a href="http://(https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/126121">making graphic software do what you want</a>`
- Skeptics: `<a href="http://​​https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39758/is-it-illegal-to-own-a-rabbit-in-queensland-unless-youre-a-magician">the bizarre​</a>`
- Parenting: `<a href="http://or parents, grandparents, nannies and others who care for children. Topics include upbringing, safety, feeding, health and hygiene, development and growth, language, behavior, and discipline.">One</a>`

Additionally, all of the sites use `http://` links, rather than `https://` for the actual link to the site.

Comment: Looks like they'll just give up soon and remove the post. It just keep taking time and resources from SE staff to keep fixing it, time after time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The links have been updated and all http has been changed to https.

Comment: @Juan you missed another one, see new bug report and also in answer to this one. I really wonder, why don't someone from SE review the blog post by clicking every link? Not you perhaps, but it's expected a post will be checked before being published. SE isn't short in money anymore, and can hire content editors that such things will be their job.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 Yup, got it and changed it out. This has been a good opportunity for us to do some internal collaboration!

Answer (score -1):

All the bugs have been fixed now and every link is now  https instead of http. However, **one bug persists** in Area 51. It is now leading to https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ which is the wrong site. Everything else is fine.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368805/wrong-area-51-meta-site-url-linked-in-blog-post, already reported.

Comment: @Ollie I have already read that post. I am trying to tell OP that this issue is left rest are resolved