# Wrong Area 51 meta site URL linked in blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, hyperlinks, blog

In the recent blog post [Celebrating the Stack Exchange sites that turned 10 years old](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/19/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/), end of the post there is a link for **Area 51** meta site.

The URL is wrongly mapped and it throws a security error.

| Current the following URL is mapped | Correct URL to be mapped |
| --- | --- |
| https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com | https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com |

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368790/typos-in-the-blog-links-prevent-some-from-working), guess I missed that one when I was looking for broken links :)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the heads up! All links are now workable and functioning correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved some time ago, as highlighted by ["Juan M" in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368805/wrong-area-51-meta-site-url-linked-in-blog-post#comment1230408_368805) (during his tenure as a staff member on Stack Overflow at that time).

> Fixed! Thanks for the heads up! All links are now workable and functioning correctly.